# How can we insert multiple rows into a table thourgh jsp and servlets?

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp, servlets

Suppopse 
we have a jsp Page having a from 
In the form we have multiple file chooser let say browse button and file name and file id.
and s single submit button.
Now to problem is ..
I have to submit files and  file id into table File in database and Filename and fileid to Details name table into database with the help of servlets.

Answer (score 0):

when you press submit button all this data is stored on the bean object.
in the java class you can access this using getter methods and store this values into database.
it is easy nothing complicated.
Since we have our form data on bean we can do any logic s on this data.